# Android skip activity on back button press

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a login screen in which the user logs in. After that the user will be taken to a main screen.

Now my problem is when the back button is pressed the user is taken to the login screen again.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

I have tried calling `finish()` right after `startActivity()` but it only made the application crash and didn't seem a good solution either.

Comment: can you call finish() after the user login is successful instead of calling it right after startActivity ?

Comment: post your stack trace from the logcat when the app crashes after calling finish

Comment: I believe @ThaneAnthem's answer is more correct. You should probably accept his answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the manifest, add `android:noHistory="true"` as an attribute of the login activity.

Comment: sir by adding this attribute , when i click on logout the app closes instead of going back to the login screen

Answer (score 10):

Calling `finish()` after `startActivity()` is the way to go. You should investigate on why it crashes in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider launching the main app and *then* launching the login screen as a custom modal dialog.

Tips for a modal launch:

1. `builder.setCancelable(false)`
2. Do *NOT* use a static method and call *show()* as in the open source EULA examples. This implementation fails if the user turns the phone. Instead use the standard pattern *onCreateDialog*, *getInstanceMyDialog*, *showDialog(int)*.
3. The modal dialog can return data if you call it using *startActivityForResult* or the modal dialog can write to a custom preferences file.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're never returning to Login activity again add `android:noHistory=true` on the manifest.
2. If you wanna go back to Login only from a particular activity (say, password activity), override `onBackPressed()`:

   `@Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
      }`

   of your 'main screen' which comes after the Login/password activity with the code below,

   `Intent homeIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    homeIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
    startActivity(homeIntent);`

   this will minimize your app on back press and won't return to Login/password activity.
3. If you want to kill the app, use

   `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`
4. to quit Application

   `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
          this.finishAffinity()
        }`